# How to put laser field into the Hamiltonian of the Schrodinger equation of a 3-level quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, laser-interaction

I read a paper about using femtosecond laser to control a 3-level quantum system. The author wrote the Schrodinger equation for the system and wrote the expression of the laser field. But I still don't know how to put the laser field into the Schrodinger equation.

Below is the Hamiltonian. The author never write anything about $u(t)$ later anymore.
[image]

Below is the dipole operator and the Gaussian laser amplitude.
[image]

Obviously $\mathcal{E}(t)$ is the laser field that the author wants to put into the Schrodinger equation and he later gave an expression for it.

[image]
[image]

How to put $\mathcal{E}(t)$ into the Hamiltonian? Shall I just let $u(t)=\mathcal{E}(t)$ in equation (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just put $u(t) \rightarrow \mathcal{E}(t)$. $A(\omega)$ is the spectrum of this field, which is hinted by the coefficient $\mathcal{E}_0$ ;). Since it is taken from a book, I suppose it is defined elsewhere in the book - perhaps there is a factor to account for transparency of the environment or something like that.

Comment: The author just put three energies in the diagonal of the $H_0$ in equation (2). The unit of energy is cm$^{-1}$. The unit of $\mathcal{E}(t)$ should be the same as $\mathcal{E}_0$, which is V/cm, as in the sentences above equation 20. If we let $u(t)=\mathcal{E}(t)$, and we want the unit of $H_0$ to match the unit of $\mu u(t)$, then $\mu \mathcal{E}(t)$ should also have the unit of cm$^{-1}$. Then the unit of $\mu$ should be V$^{-1}$. But the author says $\mu$  has arbitrary unit in equation (20). This bothers me. Why $\mu$ can have arbitrary unit?

Comment: "a.u." could be also "astronomic units" or "atomic units" - I would think the latter. Also, unless the Rabi oscillations are involved, the answer will be simply proportional to $|\mu|^2$, so its absolute value is not that important.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units